# Not able to get DATETIME from QueryString in mvc Get Controller Method (From Uri())

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datetime

```
 This is the query string that I am receiving in URL.

 Output url: /demo/analysis/test?startDate=Sat+Jun+01+2013+00%3A00%3A00+GMT-0700+(Pacific+Daylight+Time)&endDate=Fri+Sep+13+2013+00%3A00%3A00+GMT-0700+(Pacific+Daylight+Time)

 test controller:
 Public Function GetData(<FromUri()> ByVal query As Request) As HttpResponseMessage
 {
 }

 Request{
 public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
 public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
 }
```

---

Angularjs Api Code:

```
   exportFunt = function () {
            var query = generateExportData();
            Export(query);
        };


    function generateExportData() {
             return {
               startDate: viewModel.StartDate,
               endDate: viewModel.EndDate,
            };
        }

     Export: function (query) {

                $window.open('/demo/analysis/test?$.param(query), '_blank');
            }
```

Comment: Are you asking for how to teach ASP.Net MVC to interpret dates in that format?  Or are you asking how to adjust your javascript code to use a standardized format?  If so, you'll need to show us that code.

Comment: Also, `DateTime` won't be sufficient.  You are including an offset in your input, so you should use a `DateTimeOffset` type - or standardize your input to UTC.

Comment: I am adding these parameters through AngularJS codebase ....I will add that code just give me a sec...

Comment: @MattJohnson  I have updated the javascript code... but I am not sure which is a standard format to pass datetime in the url so as the asp.net  controller will be able to receive it..

Comment: Are `viewModel.StartDate` and `viewModel.EndDate` JavaScript `Date` types? Or are they already strings at that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the Javascript sending the startDate & endDate in "mm/dd/yyyy" format.
This worked as the asp.net controller method was able to get this dates in datetime type..

```
    exportFunt = function () {
        var query = generateExportData();
          query .startDate = [query.startDate.getMonth() + 1,
                         query.startDate.getDate(),
                         query.startDate.getFullYear()].join('/');
          query .endDate = [query.endDate.getMonth() + 1,
                         query.endDate.getDate(),
                         query.endDate.getFullYear()].join('/');
        Export(query);
    };
```

Comment: That's a very USA specific format.  You should be using `yyyy-mm-dd` which is ISO8601 compliant.  Also you are dropping the time and the time zone offset.  Are these important to you?

Comment: Nope Time is not of much importance in this case. I know this is a sort of patch but not a permanent fix... Currently I don't know any other way to complete this task.. but I am still working on finding some good solution to this problem..

Comment: @MattJohnson thanks for your patience and time.... If you have any inputs for me to move ahead with another solution please let me know...thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't require times, I'll assume that you are selecting whole calendar dates from some sort of date-picker.  Simply pass your dates as strings in `yyyy-mm-dd` format:

```
function pad(n) {
  return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n;
}

function getDateString(dt) {
  return [dt.getFullYear(),pad(dt.getMonth()+1),pad(dt.getDate())].join('-');
}

function generateExportData() {
    return {
        startDate: getDateString(viewModel.StartDate),
        endDate: getDateString(viewModel.EndDate)
    };
}
```

Or if you don't want to write all of this yourself, you might consider using the excellent [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) library:

```
function generateExportData() {
    return {
        startDate: moment(viewModel.StartDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        endDate: moment(viewModel.EndDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    };
}
```